# Python: Creating all variables return after a loop

Tags: python

So basically I really don't know how to correctly explain this question, but what I want to achieve is:

- Firstly get and become ready to load a JSON response. - DONE
- Then load each of the cameras with -  `for i in range of(self.total_cameras)` This will run the bool and get all the info for as many cameras that are in response, for example, I have - 3.

But there is one problem that I cannot solve, the load process is working correctly, but I need to know which camera info is loaded and then make a return to the webserver to load all the cameras in google map.
The response is based on working cameras from the back-end.

For example - `return render_template('MAIN_index.html', First_Camera_ID=self.CameraID, Second_Camera_ID=self.CameraID)`

How can I make a return with all the camera's information?

Format of the JSON response:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "total_cameras": 3,
    "cameras": [
        {
            "camera_id": 3,
            "camera_name": "hikvision 1",
            "camera_ip": "73.2.51.0",
            "camera_lat": 53.736406,
            "camera_log": 15.11621,
            "camera_street": "slezeviciaus g. 7",
            "camera_lastUPD": "10 jan 16:04 2020"
        },
        {
            "camera_id": 4,
            "camera_name": "hikvision 2",
            "camera_ip": "213.2.51.0",
            "camera_lat": 51.67,
            "camera_log": -5.06,
            "camera_street": "Stanevy 4",
            "camera_lastUPD": "10 Jan 2020 07:17:37"
        },
        {
            "camera_id": 5,
            "camera_name": "hikvision 3",
            "camera_ip": "45.89.25.1",
            "camera_lat": -42.683,
            "camera_log": 41.856,
            "camera_street": "Kudirkos st",
            "camera_lastUPD": "10 jan 16:04 2020"
        }
    ]
}



# LOAD Everything                   
JSON_DATA = json.loads(self.Request_To_Server.text)
self.Cameras = JSON_DATA["total_cameras"]
for i in range(self.Cameras):
    self.Camera_name = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_name"]
    print(f'Loading {self.Camera_name} Camera info...')
    self.Camera_Lat = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_lat"]
    self.Camera_Log = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_log"]
    self.Camera_Street = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_street"]
    self.Camera_IP = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_ip"]
    self.Camera_ID = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_id"]
    self.Camera_LASTUPDATED = JSON_DATA["cameras"][i]["camera_lastUPD"]
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to pass the list of cameras to your template instead of individual cameras? You can pass anything you want as template context: `render_template('index.html', cameras=self.cameras)`

Comment: No, I need to pas one variable individually, for example Camera1_ID, Camera2_Title, Camera3_IP.....

Comment: Within your template, you can loop over each camera and access all the fields on each object through dot notation.

Comment: I'm green on Javascript, so I would rather use python I guess

Comment: And also I don't use all of these as a template.

Comment: Right, this would be with the templating language you have, it looks like you're using Django or Flask, correct?

Comment: I'm using flask

Comment: in your Main_index.html file: `{% for cam in cameras %}{{ cam.camera_id }}{% endfor %}` You can loop and access all you fields in the template like this, you might want to check out the docs for Jinja (the template language I assume you are using with Flask) https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/. I'm not sure what your original question is though.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of that?